# Sending forms in Facebook applications

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Today, my almost finished Facebook application stopped working. I have some sort of a "registration" form in the app for setting the user's in-game nick and similar stuff.

The problem is that upon submitting the form, the Facebook PHP SDK insists that `$facebook->getUser()` is `NULL`. My code reacts to this by redirecting the user to `$facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => ..., etcetera))`. Then, the user is redirected back to my application by Facebook, but, of course, without the data that was posted into the form.

I assume I should probably pass some sort of a hidden element in the form so that the Facebook PHP SDK can do its magic. Could you please tell me how does one use forms in a Facebook app properly?

Comment: What version of the PHP SDK are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I finally found out that the problem lay in my code - I had a bug in session handling. Sorry for the bashing, Facebook :)

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => ... ,
'secret' => ... ,
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if (!$user) {
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
// then redirect to the $loginurl
exit();
}
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['my_guess'])) {
?>
pick a number between 1 and 10
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="my_guess">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
}  else {
print $facebook->getUser()." you picked ".$_POST['my_guess'];
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm surprised to say, yes, it does. I guess I'm going to try to bend my code closer to this working example and see if I get my application to work.

Comment: The original app still doesn't work... I looked up the communication between the user and the server in Wireshark, and it seems that the atrocity I'm fighting happens in the POST request - the other ones look pretty much the same. The difference between the working and failing capture is that while in the working one, the first 2 requests go to / and /?state=...&code=... and the 3rd one goes to /index.php, in the failing one, the last request goes to /a?b=c, which is some cool URL the framework I use generates. Is it possible that this is what's making the SDK direct me back to the login URL?